# MFC Dialog return vector

Tags: c++, mfc, vector, modal-dialog

I am creating a modal dialog box and dynamically creating textboxes based on a user specified quantity.  I then store the values of these textboxes in a vector

```
vector <CString*> textBoxText;
```

I want to pass the vector back when the dialog closes.  I tried passing a pointer into the dialog and updating the pointer in: void CRadioDialog::OnBnClickedOk().  However, that did not work.  I don't think I can do this with data exchange, is there a way for it to be done?

Thanks,

Comment: You can pass a reference in the constructor. Or, you can just create another function in the dialog class that returns a vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help, I ended up using this method which was very easy and recommended from a different forum:

I added this into the dialog.h file:

```
public:
    const std::vector<CString>& TextBoxTexts() const
    {
        return textBoxText;
    }
```

and called it in my main view:

```
CRadioDialog dialog; 
if(rDLG.DoModal() == IDOK)
{   
    vector<CString> text;
    text = dialog.TextBoxTexts();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it. Just ensure you return actual `CString` objects, not pointers!

```
vector <CString> textBoxText;
```

What is in `OnBnClickedOk` ?

Comment: that is the handler for when the "OK" button is pressed on the dialog.  Can you explain how to return it?

Answer (score 1):

assuming you have a local member CRadioDialog.h:

```
std::vector <CString> textBoxText;
```

I suggest you to use CString heare instead of CString*

you can add a method to your CRadioDialog.h:

```
void fill_my_vector( std::vector<CString>& out_vector );
```

and CRadioDialog.cpp:

```
void CRadioDialog::fill_my_vector( std::vector<CString>& out_vector )
{
    std::copy ( textBoxText.begin(), textBoxText.end(), out_vector.begin() );
}
```

you already fill you local textBoxText with your cstrings on CRadioDialog::OnBnClickedOk()

calling code:
    void main_window::caller()
    {
    ...

```
    std::vector <CString> results;

    CRadioDialog dlg;
    INT_PTR nResponse = dlg.DoModal();
    if (nResponse == IDOK)
    {
        dlg.fill_my_vector( results );
        /* USE YOUR VECTOR */
    }

...
}
```

It's not the best optiomization method but it easy to undestand.
Hope it helps.